# не работает __setitem__

Tags: python, ооп

Создан вот такой класс (сугубо в учебных целях), в котором есть список с координатами точек маршрута и средней скоростью.

```
class Track:
    def __init__(self):
        self.coords = []

    def add_point(self, x, y, speed):
        self.coords.append(((x, y), speed))

    def verify_indx(self, indx):
        if indx not in range(0, len(self.coords)):
            raise IndexError('некорректный индекс')

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        self.verify_indx(item)
        return self.coords[item]

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self.verify_indx(key)
        lst_coord = list(self.coords[key])
        list(lst_coord)[-1] = value


tr = Track()
tr.add_point(20, 0, 100)  
tr.add_point(50, -20, 80) 
tr.add_point(63.45, 1.24, 60.34)  


tr[2] = 60
c, s = tr[2]
```

и когда срабатывает строчка `print(c, s)` я ожидаю увидеть результат `(63.45, 1.24) 60`, но выводится все равно `(63.45, 1.24) 60.34`.

В `__setitem__` пробовал вместо `list(lst_coord)[-1] = value` написать `lst_coord.insert(-1, value)`, но тоже все так же. При этом когда в `__setitem__` вставил `print(lst_coord)`, выдало нужный результат.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделайте так:

```
def __setitem__(self, key, value):
    self.verify_indx(key)
    self.coords[key] = (self.coords[key][0], value)
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло, но в чем проблема моего варианта была? В список же я преобразовал, чтобы можно было изменять элементы. Или это какая-то фишка именно этого метода?

Comment: @Jur вы создали новый список, а не изменяли старый. при том дважды создали новый. 1й раз - `=list(..)`, 2й раз - `list(...)[-1]`